# python networkx finds all nodes whose shortest distance from certain node is K

Tags: python, networkx

There is a list of edges:

`list_edges = [(1, 2), (1, 100), (2, 3), ....(992309, 1000203)]`

where (a, b) means a is linked to b (directed edge)

I'm trying to find nodes whose shortest distance from certain node is K

For example, suppose I pick node 1. Then, I want to find all of nodes whose shortest distance from node 1 is K(for example K = 5)

Now, I'm using python's module networkx.

What came on my mind fist is to calculate shortest_distance for every nodes other than 1, and sort this information. However, I believe this method is highly inefficient especially for large network.

Is there any easy way or simple function in networkx that do this thing?

Comment: You can use `single_source_shortest_path` with a cutoff set to `K`.  You will get the paths of length less than `K`, but those have to be calculated anyway.  So you can just filter them out

Comment: I appreciate your help:) I will give it a shot!